# Laravel сложный запрос

Tags: php, laravel

Требуется выполнить сложный запрос. Опишу проблему. Есть модель у который есть свойства `type` и 3 связи (relation) ( `news` `post` `video`). Мне требуется загрузить все модели и в зависимости от значение type использовать связь т.е. что то типа

```
if($models->type == 1) $models->with('video');
elseif($models->type == 2) $models->with('post');
```

это конечно не будет работать но абстрактно думаю поможет понять. Надеюсь смог объяснить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблем тут нет совсем.

```
// 1 сначала загружаешь модели (например 100 штук)
/** @var Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection $models */
$models = MyAwesomeModel::where(/*...*/)->take(100)->get();
// 2 группируешь модели по типу (есть же такое поле)
$modelsGrouped = $models->groupBy('type'); 
/* получается коллекция типа 
[
  1 => [
    [id=>1,type=>1],
    [id=>3,type=>1]
  ], 
  2=>[
    [id=>2, type=>2],
    [id=>4, type=>2]
  ]
]
*/

// 3 при помощи метода коллекции load() загружешь нужные отношения
// тут используется хэлпер optional, который проксирует вызов метода `load` 
// на коллекцию группы, или ничего не делает, если нет группы с заявленным типом
optional($modelsGrouped->get(/*type*/1))->load('video');
optional($modelsGrouped->get(/*type*/2))->load('post');
```